# Linux utility for gather statistics about a codebase

Tags: open-source, software-development, statistics

Suppose I have some software project I'm working on, and I want to compute some statistics about it:

- Number of lines (total & per file)
- Comment, spacing and other lines
- Numbers of functions, classes, methods
- Average length of a file, a function, a class, a method
- Cyclomatic complexity
- Dependency DAG depths for files, types etc.

I'll settle for only some of these, of course - the more the merrier. I do not guarantee the repository has any form of source control (although personally I'm working with mercurial right now); and it's not a clone of an online repository (so nothing like gitstats).

Requirements:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Works on Linux (AMD x86_64 CPUs)
- Supports at the very least C, C++98, C++11
- Support for multiple output formats
- Can produce output as console "ASCII-art" charts (a-la, say, `hg diff --stat`)

Desirable feature:

- Small standalone utility
- Not too many dependencies on other programs and libraries
- Fast

Answer (score 1):

[CLOC - Count Lines of Code](http://cloc.sourceforge.net) - does some (not all) of those things, meeting all the requirements. It's also fast, small, and depends only on perl and a couple of perl libs.

Sample outout:

```
http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.60  T=0.46 s (354.6 files/s, 64728.0 lines/s)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C/C++ Header                    108           2761           2452          10226
C++                              47           1626            772           9703
make                              1            476            193            931
Bourne Again Shell                3             50             25            346
CMake                             2             48             68            225
XML                               1              0              0             11
YAML                              1              1              6              8
Bourne Shell                      1              1              2              5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                            164           4963           3518          21455
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cross platform python metrics library that gives you metrics either on a single file, or can recurse a directory tree. It is available from [the original project](https://github.com/markfink/metrics) or [my fork](https://github.com/GadgetSteve/metrics) *adds recursive option* on github.

Running on an old project that I have to hand with the recurse option:

```
Files                       Language        SLOC Comment McCabe
----- ------------------------------ ----------- ------- ------
 102                            XML       10601    2415      0
   7                            VGL        4837      14     49
 588                              C      441797  135164  11715   
 302                              D        7750       0      0    
  27                           XSLT         691     313      0    
  13                         Python         881     203    141
   4                        XML+PHP       21489       0      0
  38                       Makefile        1747    3948     18
   7                      Batchfile          45       8      7
   2                           HTML           9      36      0    
  17                      Text only           0       0      0
   1                         POVRay           8      19      0
----- ------------------------------ ----------- ------- ------
1108                          Total      489855  142120  11930
```

- Libre **Yes**
- Gratis **Yes**
- Works on Linux (AMD x86_64 CPUs) **Yes** *it's python*
- Supports at the very least C, C++98, C++11  **Yes**
- Support for multiple output formats  **Yes** *Can output as text, xml or csv*
- Can produce output as console "ASCII-art" charts (a-la, say, hg diff --stat)  **Yes** *See above*
- Small standalone utility *Small, (tiny), python library that adds command line utility*
- Not too many dependencies on other programs and libraries *Depends on python, its standard libraries & pygments*
- Fast *Reasonably so*

Comment: How does it compare with CLOC w.r.t. the kinds of statistics it gathers and presents? Beyond overall line breakdown into code/comments/space ? Also, what is "McCabe"?

Comment: McCabe is the cyclomatic complexity.