# Tool for extracting metrics from C source code

Tags: open-source, c

Does any open source tool exist that can extract metrics from original C code?
Metrics like

no. of LOC
no. of assignments
no. of selection statements
no. of iteration statements
no. of switch statements
no. of returns 
no. of type parameters
no. of try statements
no. of variable declaration statements
no. of expression statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux utility for gather statistics about a codebase](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36961/linux-utility-for-gather-statistics-about-a-codebase). (There are currently [23 questions on code metrics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+code+metrics) on the site).

Comment: 'Try` statements? In C ??